# UrlRewriterFilter problema carregar css e js

Tags: php, javascript, java, jquery, css

Estou utilizando taglib como template para carregar cabeçalho, corpo e rodapé em minhas páginas jsp. Para URLS amigáveis utilizo UrlRewriteFilter. O problema é acontece quando passo parametros na URl amigáveis, pois não carrega os arquivos css e js.

A página http://localhost:8080/admin/home, carrega normalmente e o arquivo urlrewrite está assim:

```
<rule
   <from>^/home</from>
   <to>/pages/home.jsp</to>
</rule>
```

Já a página http://localhost:8080/admin/servico/48331006151024222123772 não carrega os arquivos css e js.

```
<rule>
   <from>^/servico/([0-9]+)$</from>
   <to>/pages/service.jsp?key=$1</to>
</rule>
```

Existem alguma forma na qual eu poderia deixar o path dos arquivos css e js padrão para carregar em todas às páginas, sem acontecer essa problema?

Comment: Sem o filter carrega normalmente?

Comment: Carrega normalmente sem filter. Quando acesso http://localhost:8080/admin/servico/48331006151024222123772 e eu altero o Path do css e do js carrega também. O problema que utilizo um template taglib para o projeto todo.